# Why does the EVM program counter not increase by one but by two in PUSH1 opcode?

Tags: evm, opcode

In the tutorial [here](https://eth.wiki/en/howto/ethereum-development-tutorial), the program counter increases by 2 for a PUSH1 opcode. Then it increases by 1 for other opcodes. Why is this? Does it have to do with the opcodes size in memory? Aren't they all 256 bit?

```
PC: 11 STACK: [32] MEM: [], STORAGE: {}

PC: 13 STACK: [2020202020] MEM: [], STORAGE: {}

PC: 14 STACK: [2020202020, 0] MEM: [], STORAGE: {}

PC: 16 STACK: [2020202020, 54] MEM: [], STORAGE: {}

PC: 17 STACK: [] MEM: [], STORAGE: {54: 2020202020}
```

Comment: FYI refer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77347/how-do-i-write-a-url-in-markdown-on-stack-exchange) to learn how to write a URL markdown

Comment: Hi, can you accept the answer if it helped? or need more clarification?

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the example code there

```
PUSH1 0 CALLDATALOAD SLOAD NOT PUSH1 9 JUMPI STOP JUMPDEST PUSH1 32 CALLDATALOAD PUSH1 0 CALLDATALOAD SSTORE
```

the indexing is arranged as;

0 -> PUSH1

1 -> 0

2 -> CALLDATALOAD

3 -> SLOAD 
......

In the program 0, it refers to PUSH1 and pushes the value at 1 to stack and the next instruction at the 2 should be executed. Hence the PC becomes 2.

Answer (score 0):

The EVM increases the program counter (PC) by one for all opcodes *except* for PUSH and its derivatives. As per the docs on [Source Mappings](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/internals/source_mappings.html):

> Each of these elements corresponds to an instruction, i.e. you cannot use the byte offset but have to use the instruction offset **(push instructions are longer than a single byte)**.

Thus when the EVM sees this:

```
PUSH1 0
```

It will increase the PC by two, because there is firstly the `PUSH1` opcode, and then there is `0`, the value pushed on the stack.