# Is the vm trace step in the Remix debugger the program counter?

Tags: remix, evm, contract-debugging

When debugging an Ethereum transaction with Remix, there is a section called "Step details" on the left-hand side of the screen:

[image: Remix step details]

Is the "vm trace step" the same as the [program counter](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12797/what-is-the-program-counter-at-the-start-of-an-ethereum-method-execution)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's just a linear counter that disregards the [EVM rule](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/109351/24693) that push instructions increase the program counter (PC) by at least 2 (as compared to all others opcodes, which increase the PC by 1).

The program counter is to be found on the column on the left-hand side, next to the opcodes:

[image: Opcodes]